# Is there any way to replace values of df in R using sum of rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, recode, rowsum

I have an issue which looks like easy to solve, but I'm stuck. I have a dataframe composed of columns (significant pathways retrieved from GSEA) and rows (entrez gene ids). In this data frame there are 1 if a gene is present in a pathway or 0 when not. This is my data frame:

```
                         Path_A      Path_B       Path_C
Gene_1                   0           1            0
Gene_2                   1           1            0
Gene_3                   0           0            1
Gene_4                   1           1            1
```

I want to sum the rows (genes) to calculate how many times a gene is present in distinct pathways, and thus get something like this:

```
                          Path_A      Path_B       Path_C
Gene_1                   0           1            0
Gene_2                   2           2            0
Gene_3                   0           0            1
Gene_4                   3           3            3
```

At this point, I tried using `my_df <- mutate(my_df, sum = rowSums(my_df))` to create a new column **sum** and then recode the 1 with sum value for each pathway column; however, I failed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` but the base R solution akrun posted is more reasonable:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(Path_A:Path_C, ~ .x * rowSums(across(Path_A:Path_C))))
```

returns

```r
       Path_A Path_B Path_C
Gene_1      0      1      0
Gene_2      2      2      0
Gene_3      0      0      1
Gene_4      3      3      3
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked really fine! Both answers solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use `rowSums`, replicate by row and assign it to the rows

```
df1[] <- rowSums(df1, na.rm = TRUE)[row(df1)] * df1
```

-output

```
> df1
       Path_A Path_B Path_C
Gene_1      0      1      0
Gene_2      2      2      0
Gene_3      0      0      1
Gene_4      3      3      3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Path_A = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Path_B = c(1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L), Path_C = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("Gene_1", 
"Gene_2", "Gene_3", "Gene_4"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` variation:
I thought to use `across` with `rowSums`, but as I recently learned: Using `.` in the `rowSums` bypasses the `across()` we could do it with a `helper` column:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(helper = rowSums(.)) %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. != 0, helper, .))) %>% 
    select(-helper)
```

```
       Path_A Path_B Path_C
Gene_1      0      1      0
Gene_2      2      2      0
Gene_3      0      0      1
Gene_4      3      3      3
```

Comment: Doesn't matter at all, but I think you could remove the `ifelse` function and simplify to `~(. != 0) * helper)`. The condition inside the brackets evaluates to `FALSE` for `0` which is basically `0`.